# Jekyll front matter ending in dots?

Tags: jekyll

Chasing down a problem, I happened to notice that jekyll/convertible.rb's read_yaml() routine seems to allow the frontmatter to be terminated either with three dashes, or with three dots:

```
    if content =~ /\A(---\s*\n.*?\n?)^((---|\.\.\.)\s*$\n?)/m
```

I don't find the "dots" form documented anywhere. Does it mean something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's specified in the [YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), in §2.2. It's one way to specify the end of a YAML document.